# What is the best deign approch to convert 5 windows form applications into 1 asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, software-design

I have 5 independent applications in .NET windows form , The manager decided to convert all these applications into one web application

what is the best design that help reduce complexities

the five applications will be developed in web based by 5 programmers,each will be assigned one .Then we will start the integration in one web based

I already search for modular design which use MVC4 , but since the 5 programmers are not skilled in MVC am looking to other designs that can do the job

Comment: If you're doing a rewrite you should also take the chance to restructure the work and work as *one* team, with shared ownership of the code. MVC4 is now old, you should use MVC5.x or look at a client-side library such as Angular.

Comment: @AndersAbel , Is Angular will allow reusing the code. ?